# What's the canonical method for sharing localized ui strings between Microsoft's MVC and Javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm designing an application with a dynamic, javascript based, client - which will require some localization.

The application contains significant ui components which aren't javascript generated, and are served through various MVC views.

I'd like to be able to only localize my strings once (whether they are used in Javascript, or as part of a view). Right now, I'm using resource file to localize the strings for MVC, and i'm thinking of generating a dedicated view, which will generate a localized javascript file, storing all of the strings into a namespace (that is, a view which serves something like this:

```
localized = {
WelcomeMessage: @Resource.Welcome,
Logout: @Resource.Logout,
}
```

Is there a prescribed, or canonical, method for achieving this when combining an MVC served service, with a complex javascript client?

Comment: Write them out in views as data attributes that you can grab by some convention defined in your JS?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how big your client-side code is. If you have a kilobyte or more of localised text then it would be worth moving them into a dynamically-generated "JavaScriptStrings.js" file which would be loaded by a separate `<script>` element. You can take advantage of the HTTP `Expires` header to force client-caching and thus not harm performance at all.

Commentator @AntP has a point about using `data-` attributes, but this might become unmanageable quickly. The other option is to return it inline in the HTML response, it's simpler and would be faster for clients, unless you have a lot of strings to return and/or you're serving mobile clients.